# problem with python and sql query for select entire month

Tags: python, sql

I have no problem with

```
query = 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO totalbtc5mbydate(total) SELECT SUM(amount) FROM btc5m where transactionDate like "01-04%"'
c.execute(query)
```

I got the sum in total

but doesn't work with

```
last_month = (datetime.date.today().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%m-%Y")

query = 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO totalbtc5mbydate(total) SELECT SUM(amount) FROM btc5m where transactionDate like "last_month"'
c.execute(query)
```

I got the error

sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: totalbtc5mbydate.total

Comment: You gives last month as a string and not a variable. Maybe you should try `c.execute(query, (last_month,))`

Answer (score 0):

you are not use the variable last_update.

Switch to prepared statements

```
last_month = (datetime.date.today().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%m-%Y")

query = 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO totalbtc5mbydate(total) SELECT SUM(amount) FROM btc5m where transactionDate like %s'
c.execute(query,(last_month ,))
```

Answer (score 0):

The query that you are running is

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO totalbtc5mbydate(total) SELECT SUM(amount) FROM btc5m where transactionDate like "last_month"
```

Try with

```
last_month = (datetime.date.today().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%m-%Y")
query = 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO totalbtc5mbydate(total) SELECT SUM(amount) FROM btc5m where transactionDate like "' + last_month + '"'
c.execute(query)
```